# How to make summary table by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table with product/customer in year:

When I checked in each customer, table column for each customer appear, when I unchecked, customer column hide.

Now I have to make summary table of using product quantity.

## Table

```
<div class="container">
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="John" checked="checked" /> John</p>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Adam" checked="checked" /> Adam</p>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Paul" checked="checked" /> Paul</p>
    <h2>Customers Table</h2>
    <p>Customer with Table</p>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Year/Product Quantity</th>
                <th class="John">John</th>
                <th class="Adam">Adam</th>
                <th class="Paul">Paul</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <th>2010</th>
            <th class="John">10</th>
            <th class="Adam">20</th>
            <th class="Paul">30</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2011</th>
            <th class="John">20</th>
            <th class="Adam">40</th>
            <th class="Paul">60</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2012</th>
            <th class="John">30</th>
            <th class="Adam">80</th>
            <th class="Paul">70</th>
        </tr> 
    </table>
</div>
```

And **script js** is :

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).hide();
});

$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).toggle();
});
```

## Example:

Therefore, When I checked in John,Adam, summary table will sum the quantity of two column (10+20 =30) and find out the average and condition of checked in columns.

Just like this table:

```
<p>Summery Table</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Year/Product Quantity</th>
            <th>Average</th>
            <th>Condition</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <th>2010</th>
        <th>15</th>
        <th>Good</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>2011</th>
        <th>40</th>
        <th>Good</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>2012</th>
        <th>60</th>
        <th>Good</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Let, if average > 10, is good, otherwise bad.

So that how can I produce this table in Javascript/jQuery ?
Please help me.

Comment: i think, you need to change html structure. because when you get the quantity using class name than you face some problem. i think you need to use data attribute

Comment: How ? Could you please describe elaborately ?

Comment: yes i can

$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).hide();
});

$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).toggle();

    // test 1
    var checkbox = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    $.each(checkbox, function(index, el) {
        var checkbox_name = $(el).attr('name'),
            td_text = $("table ." + checkbox_name).text();


        console.log(checkbox_name, td_text);
    });
    
});

Comment: i try this way. but the result is 
John John10
Adam Adam20

Comment: because you use the class sam class name 
<th class="John">John</th> and <th class="John">10</th>
thats why when i get the quantity it's return John10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get all visible amount from customer table using `map()` method. And then you can use reduce method to calculate total & then average.

Use `$("input:checkbox").last().change()` to set summary table values initially instead of the `each()` you are using.

**N.B:** I added different classes to differentiate two tables and used `tbody` in tables.

```js
$("input:checkbox").change(function() {
    var column = $('.customerTable').find('.' + $(this).attr("name"));
    $(column).toggle(this.checked);

    var customerTrs = $('.customerTable tbody tr'),
        summaryTable = $('.summaryTable tbody').empty();

    customerTrs.each(function() {
        var tr = $(this),
            year = tr.find('th').first().text();

        var visibleQuantities = tr.find('th:gt(0):visible').map(function() {
            return +$(this).text();
        }).get();

        var total = visibleQuantities.reduce(function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }, 0);

        var avg = total && total / visibleQuantities.length;

        var summaryTrs = '<tr><th>'+year+'</th><th>'+avg+'</th><th>'+(avg > 10 ? 'good' : 'bad')+'</th></tr>';

        summaryTable.append(summaryTrs);
    });  
});

$("input:checkbox").last().change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="John" checked="checked" /> John</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="Adam" checked="checked" /> Adam</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="Paul" checked="checked" /> Paul</p>

    <h2>Customers Table</h2>
    <table class="table customerTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Year/Product Quantity</th>
                <th class="John">John</th>
                <th class="Adam">Adam</th>
                <th class="Paul">Paul</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>2010</th>
                <th class="John">10</th>
                <th class="Adam">20</th>
                <th class="Paul">30</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>2011</th>
                <th class="John">20</th>
                <th class="Adam">40</th>
                <th class="Paul">60</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>2012</th>
                <th class="John">30</th>
                <th class="Adam">80</th>
                <th class="Paul">70</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<h2>Summery Table</h2>
<table class="table summaryTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Year/Product Quantity</th>
          <th>Average</th>
          <th>Condition</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```